# Button style does not apply to button in disabled state

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have defined default button style in App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

I see that margin does not work when button is in `Disabled` state.

`Disabled` state is handled by binding with some `ListBox.SelectedItem` property.

```
<Button Click="ButtonOpen_Click" Content="Connect">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxAddress, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style> 
                </Button>
            <Button>Close</Button>
```

I guess that my `<Button.Style>` resets everything what I have set in `App.xaml`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You override the App.xaml style by setting it directly. You could "inherit" the App.xaml style: <Style BasedOn="{StaticResources {x:Type Button}}"/>

Comment: You should post that as an answer, because it's correct.